# The Chatterbot chatbot not performing desirably after training

Tags: python, bots, training-data, chatterbot

I have just started with the Chatterbot chatbot by training it with simple statements.
It is able to answer exactly the statements that it got trained for, simple deviations it is not able to understand.
How can I make the bot intelligent enough to pick from the words that it got trained from and respond eventually?

EX: TrainData :          Hi -> Hello
TestData : Hi!  .. This should be also responded with Hello.

Apart from training the model with large corpus any configurations can be done to the bot?

Below is the sample code.

```js
import json

from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Terminal',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3',
    logic_adapters=[
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
            'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.',
            
        }
    ],
    
)

trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

trainer.train(["Hi", "Hello"])
trainer.train(["Bye", "Bye"])

bot_response = bot.get_response("Hi")
print(1),print(bot_response)

bot_response = bot.get_response("Hi there")
print(2),print(bot_response)

bot_response = bot.get_response("hi!")
print(3),print(bot_response)
```

This code returns only valid answer Hello for the first question and the next 2 questions it's not able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the answer is the default? If yes probably you should set a threshold value. Without threshold, you can not specify when to get the default.